# How resize box when using subnumcase

Tags: fonts, equations, cases, resize

I have the following problem. I have a system of two equations.
I used the package subnumcases.
Unfortunately the equations are too long and the equation number overlap the equation itself.
I tried Resizebox, to reduce the font, but they always crash. Texmaker tells that a bracket is missing. I am wondering way. I attach the code and the output.
Could you help me please?[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=238mm, left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{showframe} 
\usepackage{cases}

\begin{document}

\begin{subnumcases}{} 
 C_{a} \frac{dT_{air}}{d\theta} = H_{1} \cdot (\bar{T}_{al}-T_{air}) + H_{2} \cdot   (T_{out} -T_{air}) +q_{out} \cdot (T_{out}-T_{air}) +\Sigma \Phi_{i,c} 
    \label{eq: coupled} 
   \\
 C_{al} \frac{d \bar{T}_{al}}{d \theta} = H_{3} \cdot (T_{air} -\bar{T}_{al})+H_{4} \cdot (T_{sol}-\bar{T}_{al})+ \Sigma \Phi_{i,r}  \label{eq:system} 
\end{subnumcases}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Three solutions:

- use the `\medmath` command from `nccmath`: it reduces the size to about 80 % of `\displaystyle`,
- replace `subnumcases` by an `align` environment inside `subequations`. The brace can be obtained as an option of the `empheq` environment, and the long line will be split with either `aligned` or `multlined` (from `mathtools`, which is loaded by `empheq`):

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=238mm, left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{empheq, nccmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{showframe} \usepackage{cases}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{mathx}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{mathx}{m}{n}{
<-6> mathx5 <6-7> mathx6 <7-8> mathx7
<8-9> mathx8 <9-10> mathx9
<10-12> mathx10 <12-> mathx12
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{mathx}{U}{mathx}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{U}{mathx}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathAccent{\widebar}{0}{mathx}{"73}

\begin{document}
%
\begin{subnumcases}
{}\medmath{C_\mathrm{a} \frac{dT_\mathrm{air}}{d\theta} = H_{1} \cdot (\bar{T}_\mathrm{al}-T_\mathrm{air}) + H_{2} \cdot (T_\mathrm{out} -T_\mathrm{air}) +q_\mathrm{out} \cdot (T_\mathrm{out}-T_\mathrm{air}) +\Sigma \Phi_{i,c}} \label{eq: coupled}\\
\medmath{C_\mathrm{al} \frac{d \widebar{T}_\mathrm{al}}{d \theta} = H_{3} \cdot (T_\mathrm{air} -\widebar{T}_\mathrm{al})+H_{4} \cdot (T_\mathrm{sol}-\widebar{T}_\mathrm{al})+ \Sigma \Phi_{i,r}} \label{eq:system}
\end{subnumcases}
\bigskip

\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[left = \empheqlbrace]{align}{}C_{a} \frac{dT_\mathrm{air}}{d\theta} & = H_{1} \cdot (\bar{T}_\mathrm{al}-T_\mathrm{air}) + H_{2} \cdot (T_\mathrm{out} -T_\mathrm{air})%
\begin{aligned}[t] {}&+ q_\mathrm{out} \cdot (T_\mathrm{out}&-T_\mathrm{air}) \\[-0.8ex]
{} & +\Sigma \Phi_{i,c}\end{aligned} \label{eq:coupled}\\
\ C_\mathrm{al} \frac{d \widebar{T}_\mathrm{al}}{d \theta} & = H_{3} \cdot (T_\mathrm{air} -\widebar{T}_\mathrm{al})+H_{4} \cdot (T_\mathrm{sol}-\widebar{T}_\mathrm{al})+ \Sigma \Phi_{i,r} \label{eq-system}
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\bigskip

\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[left = \empheqlbrace]{align}%
C_{a} \frac{dT_\mathrm{air}}{d\theta} & = \!\begin{multlined}[t] %
H_{1} \cdot (\bar{T}_\mathrm{al}-T_\mathrm{air}) + H_{2} \cdot (T_\mathrm{out} -T_\mathrm{air})\\%
+ q_\mathrm{out} \cdot (T_\mathrm{out}-T_\mathrm{air}) +\Sigma \Phi_{i,c}%
\end{multlined} \label{eq:coupled}\\
\ C_\mathrm{al} \frac{d \widebar{T}_\mathrm{al}}{d \theta} & = H_{3} \cdot (T_\mathrm{air} -\widebar{T}_\mathrm{al})+H_{4} \cdot (T_\mathrm{sol}-\widebar{T}_\mathrm{al})+ \Sigma \Phi_{i,r} \label{eq-system}
\end{empheq}

\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

Also, I took the liberty to replace in your code,  `\bar` with `\widebar` (borrowed from `mathabx`), which fits better capital letters, and the subscripts as `\mathrm`.

[image]

*Edit:*

As observed by @Zarko, you also can remove the  multiplication `\cdot`s and use the `flalign` environment: this code

```
    \begin{subequations}
    \begin{empheq}[left = \empheqlbrace]{flalign}%
   {}C_{a} \frac{dT_\mathrm{air}}{d\theta} & = H_{1} (\bar{T}_\mathrm{al}-T_\mathrm{air}) + H_{2}(T_\mathrm{out} -T_\mathrm{air})+ q_\mathrm{out} (T_\mathrm{out}-T_\mathrm{air}) +\Sigma \Phi_{i,c} \label{eq:coupled}\\%
    \ C_\mathrm{al} \frac{d \widebar{T}_\mathrm{al}}{d \theta} & = H_{3}(T_\mathrm{air} -\widebar{T}_\mathrm{al})+H_{4} (T_\mathrm{sol}-\widebar{T}_\mathrm{al})+ \Sigma \Phi_{i,r} \label{eq-system}
    \end{empheq}
    \end{subequations}
```

results in

[image]

Comment: Also dots for multiplication can be omitted ... :-)

Comment: @Zarko: Right, if we use `flalign`. I've added your suggestion (with credits). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,titlepage]{book} 
\usepackage[paperwidth=165mm, paperheight=238mm, left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{showframe} 
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\parbox{1.15\linewidth}{%
\begin{subnumcases}{} 
C_{a} \frac{dT_{air}}{d\theta} = H_{1} \cdot (\bar{T}_{al}-T_{air}) + H_{2} \cdot   (T_{out} -T_{air}) +q_{out} \cdot (T_{out}-T_{air}) +\Sigma \Phi_{i,c} 
        \label{eq: coupled} \\
C_{al} \frac{d \bar{T}_{al}}{d \theta} = H_{3} \cdot (T_{air} -\bar{T}_{al})+H_{4} \cdot (T_{sol}-\bar{T}_{al})+ \Sigma \Phi_{i,r}  \label{eq:system} 
\end{subnumcases}%
}}
\end{document}
```

[image]